# WCF DataServices: Updating related object by its foreign key

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I use WCF dataservices CTP2 + EF4.1 in my project.

I want to update an entity object using wcf data service.
Here is my object:

```
    public partial class Company
{
    [Required]
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }

    public Guid Manager_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I transfer my company object to server there wcf service is stored, Manager property is null, but its foreign key Manager_Id is assigned to real manager object.

In my ef data model I have defined foreign key:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(t => t.Manager)
     .WithMany(t => t.Companies)
     .HasForeignKey(d => d.Manager_Id);
```

The problem is that it still throwing the exception that entity cannot be saved cause of validation error (manager property is required). So my question is how can I tell to wcf to save required property using its foreign key if required objects are null?

The workaround

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Property(x => x.Manager_Id).HasColumnName("Manager_Id");
```

also makes no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround solution. Just putted validation off on wcf service side.

```
 protected override MyDataContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        _mdc = new MyDataContext(@"blablalba") { TablePrefix = "vcrm_" };
        _mdc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return _mdc;
    }
```